# JavaScript Date Object Convert to 24-Hour Time

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to output a time in 24-hour format using JavaScript's Date object. So far, I have:

```js
var options = {
  timeZone: 'America/New_York',
  hour12: false
};

var dateAndTime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', options);

console.log(dateAndTime);
```

The output is something like:

```
7/19/2019, 04:41:05
```

Since I'm setting hour12: false, how come the time is still displayed in 12-hour format? I would expect to get 16:41:05 instead.

Comment: Your code is working. Can you show more details?

Comment: What is your **system** clock formatted as?  24 or 12 hour?

Comment: Which browser (version) are you using?

Comment: My system is set to a 12 hour clock. Using Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Works correctly here; it's currently 1:15pm local (Central time), and this code correctly prints `14:15:11`.  I cannot reproduce the issue with Chrome 75.0.

Comment: @Amy I noticed it works correctly in the JS Snippet, which uses another system's clock. Try the code in your JS console and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @GTSJoe I *did* try this in a JS console, and no, the snippet will use my systems clock.  The snippet, now removed (why), *also* worked correctly.

Comment: Any chance it was 4am? Because then it would be correct. and 4pm new york time hasn't occurred yet.

Comment: If it would use the _12-hour_ format then it would show a `AM` or `PM` after the time. Not showing that indicates that you tested it actually on a system at which the time in `America/New_York` was 4am. So that system might be wrongly configured. Please show the output of `console.log(Date.now()+ '  '+(new Date().toLocaleString( 'en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York', hour12: false } )))` that is generated by the system that displays the wrong time.

Comment: @CalIrvine hit the nail on the head. The problem was my system was incorrectly set to 4 AM instead of PM (not by me, but by whoever set it up). Thank you all for your help and input. I appreciate it.